# Excel VBA - Turn On ActiveX Checkbox When a Series of Subsequent Checkboxes are All Turned On

Tags: excel, list, vba, checkbox

All-

First poster, so I apologize in advance if I do something wrong here, or (more likely) post a very simple question.

I am currently making a large checklist in Excel using a series of checkboxes.  Some "main checkboxes" have a sub-series of checkboxes below them (i.e. mini-tasks or steps that make up another task).  What I want to be able to do is have the main checkbox turn on (become checked) when ALL of the sub-series of checkboxes are checked.  Is there a simple VBA answer to doing that?  I'm sure there is, but I can't seem to find it.

This is how it's basically set up:

Main Check Box Task One

```
      Step One Check Box
      Step Two Check Box
      Step Three Check Box
```

Thank you all, in advance, for all of your assistance on this one, as I'm relatively new to using VBA in Excel outside of a few simple commands.

(Edit: 8/28/2014)

I think it may be easier if I just provide the code here, as I'm having a hard time following.  The VBA that I currently have set up is designed to mirror checkbox clicks.  Basically, if one checkbox is selected on sheet "New Product - Prod Dev", that selection is mirrored on sheet "New Product Overview".  What I want to happen is that if checkboxes "NPProdDevCB1", "NPProdDevCB2", "NPProdDevCB3", and "NPPRodDevCB4" are checked, then "NPProdDevMainCB" is automatically clicked.

This is what I have set up to do the mirroring between sheets:

Private Sub NPProdDevMainCB_Click()

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product - Prod Dev").NPProdDevMainCB = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product Overview").NPOCBA = True
Else
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product - Prod Dev").NPProdDevMainCB = False Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product Overview").NPOCBA = False
End If
End If
```

End Sub

Private Sub NPProdDevCB1_Click()

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product - Prod Dev").NPProdDevCB1 = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product Overview").NPOCB1 = True
Else
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product - Prod Dev").NPProdDevCB1 = False Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product Overview").NPOCB1 = False
End If
End If
```

End Sub

Private Sub NPProdDevCB2_Click()

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product - Prod Dev").NPProdDevCB2 = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product Overview").NPOCB2 = True
Else
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product - Prod Dev").NPProdDevCB2 = False Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product Overview").NPOCB2 = False
End If
End If
```

End Sub

Private Sub NPProdDevCB3_Click()

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product - Prod Dev").NPProdDevCB3 = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product Overview").NPOCB3 = True
Else
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product - Prod Dev").NPProdDevCB3 = False Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product Overview").NPOCB3 = False
End If
End If
```

End Sub

Private Sub NPProdDevCB4_Click()

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product - Prod Dev").NPProdDevCB4 = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product Overview").NPOCB4 = True
Else
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product - Prod Dev").NPProdDevCB4 = False Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New Product Overview").NPOCB4 = False
End If
End If
```

End Sub

Please let me know the best way to set this code up to account for auto-clicking when subsequent checkboxes are all turned on.

Again, thanks for all your help here, and I apologize if I'm missing the easy fix (I probably am).

Answer (score 0):

put something like this in the click even for your first checkbox

ActiveSheet.CheckBox2.Enabled = Not ActiveSheet.CheckBox2.Enabled

Comment: Yeah, that didn't really help.  It seems like this should be easy, but I can't find a straightforward answer to the question that works anywhere, haha.  Thanks though, for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable outside of any subroutines (such as for the checkboxes).

```
Dim boxesChecked = 0
```

Then, in each checkbox's subroutine, put this:

```
if [sub checkbox name].value = true Then
    boxesChecked = boxesChecked + 1
else
    boxesChecked = boxesChecked - 1
```

In the last sub checkbox, put this there:

```
if [sub checkbox name].value = true Then
    boxesChecked = boxesChecked + 1
else
    boxesChecked = boxesChecked - 1

if boxesChecked = [number of sub checkboxes] Then
    [main checkbox name].value = true
else
    [main checkbox name].value = false
```

I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you for the help, but I couldn't get that to work.  To complicate things further, I already have Private Subs for clicks on all of the checkboxes to link them all back to a main "Overview" page.  Maybe I'm putting your answer in the wrong place?

Comment: Yes, the if statements should go into those Private Subs for the checkbox clicks.

Comment: If I want to use the VBA code that's already in the checkbox click Private subs AS WELL as this code, is it just another if statement?

Comment: Just put that code outside the if statements.  Then it should work.